# Imports with typescript

Tags: typescript

I begin a new project with typescript and I have questions about imports.
Let's assume I have these 2 files:

```
// foo.ts
namespace root {
    export class Test {
        constructor() {
            console.log(BAR)
        }
    }
}

// a/bar.ts
namespace root.a {
    export const BAR = 'Whatever'
}
```

How can I use my BAR const into my Test class?
I tried to add `/// <reference path="a/bar.ts" />` and then I can call `root.a.BAR` or even `a.BAR`.

But I would prefer to not use this reference statement, is it possible?
Also, I would like to use `BAR` without its full namespace, is it also possible?

Thank you in advance,
Xavier

Answer (score 1):

> I would prefer to not use this reference statement, is it possible

Yes, you would use tsconfig.json : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/compilation-context/tsconfig

but beware of ordering pain (you will need to order using `files`) : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Instead use modules.

## More

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: I would expand the answer a bit more and rely less on external links to your own website. The reply is helpful and correct nonetheless though. Btw, thanks for the awesome work on the book, I reference it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, basarat.

I use *namespaces* because I don't want to set up something like RequireJS, required by *modules*. But if I understand well, it is not the right way to solve my problem.

I tried to follow this example (typescript + angular 1): [hottowel-angular-typescript by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/hottowel-angular-typescript/tree/master/src/client/app) but is it really a good example? I mean, I really don't want to prefix every class / interface / const ... by its namespace!

Is there another solution without file modules?